# How to insert multiple rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple rows in mysql,
i have data which is going to get inserted ( **id_order** - **`5561,5560`** & **id_employee** = **1**
**current_state** = **"1"**).
So there are two order ids so two different rows should added ideally one with **"5561"** another with **"5560"**

```
INSERT INTO order_history SELECT NULL AS id_order_history,? AS id_employee, id_order, current_state AS id_order_state, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS date_add FROM orders WHERE id_order IN (?);
```

I am not sure how do i frame the values into the above query
any thoughts ?

Comment: from second table you should select with column names as it is in first table
and exact in the same count

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, would you prefer adding as answer ? That will be helpful

Comment: in your sql there is 2 tables
sco_orders and sco_order_history

Comment: it would be helpful if you add your tables examples. You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables for that.

Answer (score 0):

from second table you should select with column names as it is in first table and exact in the same count

Comment: I cannot correct the query because I don't know the column names in your database